# Wordpress: > is being displayed as &gt;

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I am using Wordpress 4.9 with Jetpack markdown and SyntaxHighlighter Evolved plugin.

```
[python]
>>>
>>> import datetime
>>> current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> current_datetime
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 24, 13, 59, 42, 135163)
>>> print(current_datetime)
2017-01-24 13:59:42.135163
>>>
[/python]
```

The above code is being displayed as:

[image]

I have already disabled the visual editor. So what's the problem then

Comment: I am having the same problem. Even I know "SyntaxHighlighter Evolved plugin" is not required, Or any other plugin.  JetPack + Markdown will just do it. And no shortcodes are required. Just use "\`\`\`python my code \`\`\`" ... Or "\`\`\`cpp my code \`\`\`" ... Still less than and greater then ar rendered as html escape codes for them,

Comment: Testing the SO comments markdown: ```cpp < < > >>``` .. yes that comes out fine. no syntax highlighting but less then and greater then are rendered ok. not as html escape codes...

Comment: I have given it some due diligence.  The "Evolved" plugin is apparently co-developed by Automattic too and "built-in" into the Jetpack to do the SH for the markdown documents transformed with JetPack (part of JetPack the setup) ... I have given up on both and went back to "Crayon"  and no Jetpack MarkDown, as ever in the last few years... Now waiting for the JP support to answer my email.. HTH